# Single spaced long chapter title with double spacing between different chapter titles in table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, titletoc

I am preparing the table of contents for my thesis via the `titletoc` package. Specifically, I have a long chapter title that continues through multiple lines which are double spaced. However, I need them to be single spaced. For the rest of the table of contents, i.e., spacing between different chapter titles must be double spaced. Is there a specific way through which I can do this in the `titletoc` package?

[image: A Sample Table of Contents]

Attached is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} %% changes toc entry appearance
\newcommand{\setupname}[1][\chaptername]{
    \titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1ex}}{#1~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{}{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\contentspage}[]
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\mdseries\large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{\centering}
\begin{document}
    \begin{spacing}{1.75}
        \renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
        \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage
        \setupname
        \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
        \lipsum
        
        \section{Problem Statement and Organization}
        \lipsum
        
        \section{Detailed Investigations}
        \lipsum

        \chapter{I AM A VERY LONG CHAPTER, BUT I NEED TO BE SINGLE SPACED USING THE TITLETOC PACKAGE}
        \lipsum
                
        \section{Problem Statement and Organization}
        \lipsum
        
        \section{Detailed Investigations}
        \lipsum
        
        \chapter{CONCLUSION}
        \lipsum
        
    \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Vikram, could you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: Hi @DrecksHippy, I have included the code that I am using. Thank you for your help.

Comment: the MWE would be more helpfull if you removed the unnecessary lines ;)
But is it an option for you, to put the `\tableofcontents` command outside the `spacing` environment and then change the `\vspace{1ex}` in your `\setupname` command to `\vspace{1.75\baselineskip}`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in my comment to the question, you can put the `\tableofcontents` outside the `spacing` environmont to prevent more linespacing in the first place. Then to get back the additional space between to entries in the toc, add some space in the 3rd parameter of the `\titlecontents` command, that is the code that's put before every toc entry:

```
documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}

\newcommand{\setupname}[1][\chaptername]{ % set \vspace to 1.75\baselineskip
    \titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1.75\baselineskip}}{#1~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{}{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\contentspage}
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\mdseries\large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{\centering}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
    \begin{spacing}{1.75}
        \cleardoublepage
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \setupname
        \chapter{INTRODUCTION}\label{chap:intro}
        
        \chapter{I AM A VERY LONG CHAPTER, BUT I NEED TO BE SINGLE SPACED USING THE TITLETOC PACKAGE}\label{chap:intro}
        
        \chapter{REFERENCES}
        
    \end{spacing}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't enclose the whole document in a `\spacing` environment: just issue `\setstretch{1.75}` in the document preamble. You can set `\singlespacing` in the code for the `\titlecontents`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\mdseries\large}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}
  {1em}
  {\centering}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]
  {\vspace{1ex}\singlespacing}
  {\chaptername~\thecontentslabel:\quad}
  {}
  {\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\contentspage}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} %% changes toc entry appearance

\setstretch{1.75}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum

\section{Problem Statement and Organization}
\lipsum

\section{Detailed Investigations}
\lipsum

\chapter{I AM A VERY LONG CHAPTER, BUT I NEED TO BE SINGLE SPACED USING THE TITLETOC PACKAGE}
\lipsum

\section{Problem Statement and Organization}
\lipsum

\section{Detailed Investigations}
\lipsum

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]